# Как быть с .mp3 в опере?

Tags: opera, html, webbrowser, mp3, аудио

```
 <audio class="player" preload="auto" controls>
    <source class="player" src="music/1.mp3">
</audio>
```

Работает везде, кроме оперы. Выяснил, что опера не поддерживает .mp3. Выходит, теперь надо в 2 раза больше файлов хранить или есть другой способ выводить mp3 файлы в этом браузере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите вот это --> [audio.js — слушаем музыку в любом браузере](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110906/)